# Covariant derivative of the Ricci tensor using pure algebra

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus, differentiation

I want to differentiate the Ricci tensor covariantly, namely without using Bianchi identities and with pure algebra, I want to prove:

$$
D _{\mu} R^{\mu\nu} = {{1}\over{2}} g^{\mu\nu} \partial_{\mu}R
$$

The problem is that I get lost in indices so fast, and it becomes so frustrating. Am I missing out on symmetries? What are the steps that I need to take? Should I first write the Ricci tensor in terms of the Christoffel symbols?

Comment: Why do you say that the "pure algebra" calculation is covariant?

Comment: @Prahar What I meant was without using the Bianchi identities, which is trivial. Only by algebra, substitution, covariant differentiation, and so on. We know what the Ricci tensor is in terms of the Christoffel symbols and we know what those are in terms of derivatives of the metric and we know how to covariantly differentiate a tensor. But where should I start without making a big mess of indices?

Comment: Are you willing to use normal coordinates ?

Comment: I would say to use the longer you can the abstract properties of covariant differentiation (linearity, leibniz rule, etc), and only then expand everything in components. It will still be tedious, but you'll be able to divide up the calculation

Comment: @Avantgarde It's in the book 'General Relativity The Theoretical Minimum' by Leonard Susskind, and also that's how he derives the Einstein field equation and the Einstein tensor G in his Stanford lectures. In his book, he derives $D _{\mu} (g^{\mu\nu}R)=g^{\mu\nu}\partial_{\mu}R$ only, which is not difficult at all and he mentions that the other one is "a little harder, but not much". Yet I have a hard time deriving it.

Comment: @Avantgarde I think the identity in the OP is correct. It also appears [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_formulas_in_Riemannian_geometry) as the "twice-contracted second Bianchi identity". Tensorial information isn't discarded since $\partial_\alpha R = \nabla_\alpha R$

Comment: Ah, I missed the indices, you're right! https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contracted_Bianchi_identities